# Import Module with an different user account

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Are you able to import a module through PowerShell with a different user account? I am specifically attempting to import the ActiveDirectory module with a different account to the currently logged in one.

I don't want to go all out for the console though because I am attempting to use the current Outlook process to send an email after the part of the code is done, and if the entire console is elevated it will give a COM error (instance of PowerShell and Outlook are not elevated together).

The SMTP way of sending an email or through Send-Mail won't work as even though I can ping the SMTP server, I get the below error message, which from what I've read is because I am unable to communicate with the SMTP server appropriately?

> Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
>       At C:\Users\\Desktop\SCRIPT.ps1:64 char:9
>       +         $SMTP.Send($MSG)
>       +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException

Comment: You could start a new process as a different user with `psexec.exe` and then return what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import a module with a different account as it doesn't work this way. You need to run the individual commands themselves with alternative credentials.

As you mentioned AD I've used [Get-ADUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee617241.aspx) as an example but a lot of powershell commands have a `Credential` or `PSCredential` parameter of some kind, check the documentation to find out.

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential

Get-ADUser JohnSmith -Properties DistinguishedName -Credential $Credentials
```

This above example will prompt for credentials, but you can also save them in the script instead on entering them every time.

**NOTE: Saving credentials in a file isn't secure so be careful what credentials you save and where you store them!**

```
$Username = "DomainUserName"
$Password = "PlainPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username ,$Password)
```

There are also [other ways](https://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1/) to save credentials, but that's too much to go into here.

Comment: Thank you. This was what helped me - the Get-Credential and adding a -Credential parameter to each command.

Answer (score 0):

The AD module for powershell is a wrapper around much of the .NET framework's System.DirectoryServices namespace of code.

.NET in turn is wrapped on top of the older COM ADSI component.

Because of this, it is possible to use windows cached credentials to handle the AD work without using the -Credential option.

If you cache a Windows Domain credential prior to running the script, the AD cmdlets will use those cached credentials to authenticate to the DC.  Of course, there's no requirement to remove the cached credential...but realize it's static.  if the password changes in the domain, you need to re-cache the cred.

The management of domain creds can be done by command line as well using the [cmdkey.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754243(v=ws.11).aspx) program that is present since Win7.  Using this command line tool, you could set the windows credential just before you run your script, then remove the credential after.

Note that the use of the cached creds is based solely on the server name that the cmdlet will attempt to communicate.  If you are not specifying a DC in your cmdlet calls, then it will use the %logonserver% environment variable.

The critical piece then is that the servername used by ADSI must match exactly in the credential cache.  If the short name (server01) is used, then that must be in the cache. If the full dns name is used (server01.domain.com), then that must be in the cache.  If you feel that your script may change to another server, then that server must be in the cache.